# Sorting Algorithm [Implementing into a method]

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I Would like to find out how can use the sorting algorithm (last method of the code) in the Questions method in order for it to sort the names of each player in a order. I can't place it in the Main method as it requires the string of (names) from the loop which is in the Questions Method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int players = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please tell me how many players are taking part in this quiz!"));


            /* --------------------------- Questions in Arrays --------------------------- */ 

        String[] question = {"Question 1: ",
                         "Question 2: ",
                         "Question 3: ",
                         "Question 4: ",
                         "Question 5: " };

            String[] answer = {"ans1",
                               "ans2",
                               "ans3",
                               "ans4",
                               "ans5" };




questions(question, answer, players);

            /* --------------------------- Questions in Arrays --------------------------- */ 
}                       /* End of Main Method */




            /* Questions Method */

public static void questions(String[] question, String[] answer, int n) {

        String[] name = new String[n];  // Player Names 
        int[] playerscore = new int[n]; // Argument for Score
        String[] que = new String[question.length]; //Questions for Loops



            /* --------------------------- For loop for number of players --------------------------- */ 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        playerscore[i] = 0;
        name[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name player"+ (i+1) +"?");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello :"+ name[i] + " Player number " +(i+1)+ ". I hope your ready to start!");


            /* --------------------------- Loop in Loop for questions --------------------------- */ 
        for (int x=0; x<question.length; x++) {
            que[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question[x]);
                if(que[x].equals(answer[x]))
                    {

                        playerscore[i] = playerscore[i] + 1;

                    }

        else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong!");
             }

                } // End for loop for Question



        System.out.println("\nPlayer: "+(i+1)+ " Name: "+name[i]+"\tScore"+playerscore[i]+" out of 5.);





            /* --------------------------- Loop in Loop for questions --------------------------- */ 



           } // End for loop for player number

              } //End method questions
```

public static void sortNames(String name[]) {

```
int i;
boolean flag = true;  // will determine when the sort is finished
String temp;

  while(flag) { // while flag is true
    flag = false;
        for (i = 0; i < name.length-1; i++) {
          if (name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[i+1]) > 0 ) {
            temp = name[i];
            name[i] = name[i+1];     // swapping
            name[i+1] = temp;
            flag = true;
                }
            }
    }
```

}

```
       /* --------------------------- Score Display --------------------------- */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just let your question method return the array with the player names.
This way you can use the returned value to call the sortNames method.

Comment: When i try to return the name array from the question method it says that the value has already been declared.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use Arrays.sort() method to sort the names? You are using an complex method to sort strings.

```
public static String[] sortNames(String name[]) 
{
    Arrays.sort(name);
    return name;
}
```

For your reference [Sort Array in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

If you want to make easy then you can create an object for each player and keep it in HashMap.

You can do that using an HashMap in java with key as your player Name - String and Value as an object that contains all the information about the player you need to have.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Also you can sort that hashmap like

```
HashMap<String, PlayerInfo> map = new HashMap<String, PlayerInfo>();
ValueComparator bvc =  new ValueComparator(map);
TreeMap<String,PlayerInfo> sorted_map = new TreeMap<String,PlayerInfo>(bvc);

map.put(playerName1, playerInfo1);
map.put(playerName2, playerInfo2);

map.put(playerNamen, playerInfon);

sorted_map.putAll(map);

System.out.println("results: "+sorted_map);
```

Comment: How should i implement this into my Question method ? Ps. I used this complex method as it was an algorithm that we went through.

Comment: I would like to use the algorithm i already have, as i dont want to mess things up around the code. Is there anyways to pass the sortName method into the questions method just above the playerscore display to sort the names in order

Comment: No you can't do that with what you have as if you sort the names then corresponding scores of the players which is in another map will point to older names order. So with two different array you cant sort one alone.